# How do I associate a record with a TListBox item?

Tags: delphi, listbox

I have one record type. I want to add the variable of that record type in TListbox and retrieve it on click event of TListbox. Is it possible? If yes then how?

I added it using

```
lstbox.AddItem(data,myrec);
```

It shows error of incompatible types. data is string and myrec is variable of MyRecord which I have created.

For adding:

```
New(fptr1);
ZeroMemory(fptr1,sizeof(fptr1^));
fptr1^ := fptr^;
lstboxLeft.AddItem(path,TObject(fptr1));
```

For retrieve:

```
fptr := PData(lstboxLeft.Items[lstboxLeft.ItemIndex]);
```

Comment: You are casting "Items" when you should be casting "Items.Objects". Compare with the code in my post.

Comment: Please note that the technique works not only for TListBox, butalso for TComboBox. It works for pretty much anything that has a TStrings. In particular, it works with TStringList. (It won't work with TMemo or TRichEdit, though; those don't really have fixed lines.)

Comment: Is there any particular overriding reason to use a record? If nothing is driving that choice, I would recommend converting your record to a class. No conversion of pointers, cleaner memory handling, etc.

Comment: @Bruce Yes, there is a reason. I had to work with pointers, but its solved with the help of VilleK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AddItem takes a TObject as the second parameter and a record is not an object. You could either make your record a TObject instead (usually the best solution) or cast the record to an object.

Here is a working example using records:

```
type
  PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
  TMyRec = record
    I : integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  P : PMyRec;
begin
  New(P);
  P.I := 42;
  ListBox1.AddItem('One',TObject(P));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I : integer;
begin
  //Free memory
  for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    Dispose(PMyRec(ListBox1.Items.Objects[I]));
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P : PMyRec;
begin
  P := PMyRec(ListBox1.Items.Objects[ ListBox1.ItemIndex ]);
  ShowMessage( IntToStr(P.I) );
end;
```

Comment: @VilleK and how to access it again?

Comment: @VilleK Its not giving me value. It gives garbage value. I am using Delphi 2007

Comment: You are probably not handling the memory management correctly. Instead of declaring a TMyRecord locally in a method when adding items, declare a PMyRecord and initialize it using new (see answer by SimaWB). When you are finished with the listbox loop through the items and call dispose to free memory again.

Comment: @VilleK I am doing the same as you are saying

Comment: There are several pitfalls with using records this way so perhaps you would be better off using a TObject instead. Please update your question with the code you have problem with so it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Ville, it looks like you're adding a pointer to a local variable. You should dynamically allocate the memory as shown in Sima's answer and now in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's doing exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

```
Type    
  PMyrec = ^MyRecord;
var
  MyRec : PMyRec;  
begin
  new(MyRec);
  //fill MyRec 
  lstbox.AddItem(data, TObject(myrec));

  //Dispose
```